# ubuntu-desktop dependencies error after katoolin installed

Tags: dependencies, katoolin

While I was installing the katoolin, it automatically removed these packages:

> `ubuntu-desktop, appmenu-qt5, checkbox-gui, checkbox-converged, unity-tweak-tool, unity-webapps-common, libunity-webapps0.amd64, unity-webapps-service, webapp-container, webbrowser-app, unity-webapps-qml, qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64, qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64, qtcdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin, libubuntugestures5:amd64, libdouble-conversion1v5:amd64`

Every package depends on each others, so every time I try to reinstall them, I've got dependencies errors. Especially, I can't install ubuntu-desktop. I tried all of the commands that I found on the internet, but I cannot still solve this. How can I get them back?

Comment: I have same problem too...